# How to change query status from suspended to runnable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that needs to update 2 million records but there is no space in the disk, so the query is suspended right now. After that, I free up some space, but the query is still in suspended. So how should I change the status to Runnable or is there any way to tell sql server that you have enough space right now, and you can run the query.

Comment: Consider also asking on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

> After that, I free up some space, but the query is still in suspended.is there any way to tell sql server that you have enough space right now, and you can run the query.

SQLSERVER will change the query status from suspended to runnable automatically,it is not managed by you..

Your job here is to check ,why the query is suspended..Below dmvs can help

```
select session_id,blocking_session_id,wait_resource,wait_time,
last_wait_type from sys.dm_exec_requests
 where session_id=<< your session id>>
```

There are many reasons why a query gets suspended..some of them include locking/blocking,rollback,getting data from disk..

You will have to check the status as per above dmv and see what is the reason and troubleshoot accordingly..

Below is some sample piece of code which can help you in understanding what suspended means

```
create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
select row_number() over (order by (select null))
from
sys.objects c
cross join
sys.objects c1
```

**now in one tab of ssms:
run below query**

```
begin tran
update t1
set id=id+1
```

Open another tab and run below query

```
select * from t1
```

Now open another tab and run below query

```
 select session_id,blocking_session_id,wait_resource,wait_time,
 last_wait_type,status from sys.dm_exec_requests
 where session_id=<< your session id of select >>
```

or run below query

```
 select session_id,blocking_session_id,wait_resource,wait_time,
 last_wait_type,status from sys.dm_exec_requests
  where blocking_session_id>0
```

You can see status as suspended due to blocking,once you clear the blocking(by committing transaction) , you will see sql server automatically resumes suspended query in this case

Comment: It is because the not enough disk space that makes the query suspended. and there is only one table in the database and this table has more then 249 GB, my problem is that i need to add a new column into the database and then update that column. I set the database recovery mode to Simple but the log file is still way larger than I expect, it has more than 400 GB

Comment: What is your update statement,some akter statements are only meta data change.See if your alter fits that cruteria.Further i suggest to do updates in batches

Comment: This will not fill your log space and also try breAking up table.